# AJAX response does not get assigned to variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using this code to get the contents of **data.dat**. Here are the files:

**main.js**

```
function getData() {
  var result;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      result = this.responseText.split(",");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST","data.dat",true);
  xhttp.send();
  return result;
}
```

**data.dat**

```
A,B,C
```

However, `getData()` returns an empty string. When I log `this.responseText` this way:

```
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  console.log(this.responseText);
  result = this.responseText.split(",");
}
```

I get `["A","B","C"]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AJAX` stands for *Asynchronous JavaScript And XML*, you're using an asynchronous call in order to get your desired output. The issue is that `return result` statement is *returned* before your `AJAX` call is finished and that's why you're receiving empty result.

You should use a `callback` function.

```
function getData(callback) {
  var result;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      result = this.responseText.split(",");
      callback(result);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST","data.dat",true);
  xhttp.send();
}

getData(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```